# Combining unequal lapply dataframe output into a single dataframe R

Tags: r, dplyr

What would be the best way to combine the output of the following into a single dataframe?
My function inputs a dataframe from a list of dataframes using the lapply function. I process the data inside my lapply function and return the output. My goal is to return the output and column bind the data into a dataframe, on occasion my return output is unequal in length which is causing the bind_cols function to fail. I would appreciate your comments and input on this.

```
data <- list of dataframes. 

main <- data.frame(barcodes=..., other_info=...)

newFrame <- lapply(data, function(x){
   testFrame <- data.frame(x) %>%
   select(conc,barcodes) %>%
   full_join(main) %>%  ### main also has a column called barcodes
   select(conc) %>%
   return()
 }) %>% bind_cols()

Error: Error in `bind_cols()`:
                              ! Can't recycle `..1` (size 81) to match `..3` (size 82).
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example to help you with this problem? At the moment it's hard to know what the data frames look like, and what the desired output looks like.